# How to ensure dependency isolation in node project?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, 12factor

I 'm reading the [12-factor-app manifesto](https://12factor.net/) and stumbled upon the concept of ***dependency isolation*** [here](https://12factor.net/dependencies). I'm familiar with the concept from working in Python projects using [conda](https://conda.io/). But how can I achieve the same kind of isolation in a *nodeJS* application?

I had the case in the past where I had `eslint` installed globally but not defined in `package.json` in the project. The CI/CD failed later because of a missing dependancies. So I know how much important this can be.

Of course I can always run my apps inside isolated [docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers, but I feel like this is an overkill for local development specially for small projects.

Is there any way to ensure dependancy isolation in nodejs projects?

Answer (score 0):

I believe yarn.lock (for yarn) serves the purpose. All deps are written down there and you can store in source control

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't ensure dependancy isolation. Packages installed globally can easily leak in

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the CI/CD pipeline is a great way to make sure your dependencies are all documented.

You could create a pipeline that runs on commits and lets the developer know of any issues before the commit is merged into a main branch.